# dynamically import 100 .ts files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

It might be a dumb question but i'm really new to typescript.
Lets say I have 100 .ts files in a directory.
Is it okay to load all these files using fs module? Something like this?

`readdirSync(__dirname).filter((file: string) => file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.ts') .forEach((file: string) => { temp[file.slice(0, -3)] = require(path.join(__dirname, file); });`

If so how do i keep track of types?

Comment: Im not sure why you should do that. TypeScript was created to have more structure/definitions. Why should you load that dynamical if you dont need the structure/definitions. You can write your ts files, compile/transpile them, and then load plain js files.  (Would be interessting for what you need it) BTW: node cant handle typescript, you have to transpile them first

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're loading these files for achieving some side effects. Yes, ofcoz you can. It's even better to use `await import()` rather than `require()`.

On the type issue, you won't have any concerns about types. Because you're importing them for side effects. As long as these ts files are valid, you're fine.